# How to Check Datatype and Compare with same format

Tags: c#

```
object[] RA= {"Ram",123,122};
for(int i = 0;i< RA.Length;i++)
{
    if(RA[i].GetType().toSting()=="System.String")
    { 
        print('string');
    }
    else
    {
        print('int');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string
int
int
```

I can use `GetType()` and I have tried but it shows an error that I can compare. How this problem can be solved?

Comment: question unclear. Do you want to know if `x` can be an integer? Do you want to check x's chars to check if they are numbers (because of for loop)?

Comment: @GiladGreen sir.. How I updated the code please have a look...

Comment: @mjwills sir this code showing an error. that i cannot compare these two value.. i want when some one enter string or int in object array then it will print whether it is int or string

Comment: What do you want this code to do? You are comparing type of array elements and printing string or int. What issue you are facing in this? What more you want your code to do? Where is the comparison code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the question is asked in C# tags so i am answering with respect to C#
this gives the output you are expecting

```
 object[] RA= {"Ram",123,122};
for(int i = 0;i< RA.Length;i++)
{
  if(RA[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
  { 
     Console.WriteLine("string");
  }
  else
  {
     Console.WriteLine("int");
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason that the original didn't *compile* was because `toSting` is not `ToString` - - perhaps worth mentioning

Comment: Yes you are right #pinkfloydx33 i just realized now its available but due to spelling mistake of him it was not working

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach to it a bit differently:

- As you want to iterate the items of the collection and index doesn't matter, I'd use [`foreach` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).
- Instead of calling `GetType` and using `typeof` I'd use the [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is):

Together:

```
object[] RA = { "Ram", 123, 122 };
foreach(var item in RA)
{
    if (item is string)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int");
    }
}
```

In addition, taking it one step further I'd add a use of the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
object[] RA = { "Ram", 123, 122 };
foreach(var item in RA)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item is string ? "string" : "int");
}
```

---

Note that if you want the type name (and not the full name) just use:

```
Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the values from the array in their native types you can, as of C# 7, use pattern matching:

```
object[] RA = { "Ram", 123, 122 };
for (int i = 0; i <  RA.Length; i++) {
  var r = RA[i];
  if (r is string s) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}: string \"{s}\"");
  } else if (r is int x) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}: int {x}");
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {r.GetType().Name}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **Visual Studio 2017** and **C#7.0** you are finally able to use `switch` on types:

> [What's New in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) - Switch statements with patterns
>
> ```
> switch(shape)
> {
>     case Circle c:
>         WriteLine($"circle with radius {c.Radius}");
>         break;
>     case Rectangle s when (s.Length == s.Height):
>         WriteLine($"{s.Length} x {s.Height} square");
>         break;
>     case Rectangle r:
>         WriteLine($"{r.Length} x {r.Height} rectangle");
>         break;
>     default:
>         WriteLine("<unknown shape>");
>         break;
>     case null:
>         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(shape));
> }
> ```

---

Applied to your code:

```
object[] RA= {"Ram",123,122};
for(int idx = 0; idx < RA.Length; idx++)
{
    switch(RA[idx])
    { 
        case string s:
            Console.WriteLine($"The type of {s} is string");
            break;
        case int i:
            Console.WriteLine($"The type of {i} is int");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine($"The type of {RA[idx]} is {RA[idx].GetType().Name}");
            break;
    }
}
```